# Regex for removing all brackets except one match in particular

Tags: regex, sed

I have an expression which removes all brackets but I'd like to leave "(2017)" intact. I'm using sed to make the changes.

The expression:

```
(\([^)]+\))
```

Example data:

```
(abc2678) aaaa (2017) aaaa (def0719)
(abc2678) aaaa
(abc2678) aaaa (2017) aaaa (def0719)(def0719)
(abc2678) aaaa aaaa (def0719)(def0719)
```

Comment: You mean like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/FraZ4t/1)?

Comment: you should add expected output as well.. not clear whether you want to remove only `()` or the contents within them as well

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `sed` for this, it does not support lookarounds.

Use `perl`:

```
perl -pe -i 's/\((?!2017\))[^()]*\)//g' file
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/cE5dKz/1)

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2017                     '2017'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
```